# Need help on Replacing String in Soap XML

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a SOAP XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <hari:getRatingPlugDetailsResponse xmlns:hari="hari.cfm">
      <return>
        <jsonData>{"ratingPlugId":"ratingPlug01","partNumber":"1","keyword":"zazvgtrvdf","unitOfMeasure":"cm","upq":"1","unitListPrice":"100","currency":"currency1","leadTime":"leadTime1","validityTime":"validityTime1","rfqQuotation":"rfqQuotation1","stock":"stock1"}</jsonData>
        <httpCode>200</httpCode>
      </return>
    </hari:getRatingPlugDetailsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want replace a string in the XML dynamically in server operations.
I tried it by changing Namespace URI which doesn't work in my server.
**I just need a XSLT solution to check for "hari.cfm" and replace it with "http://hari.cfm"**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just need a XSLT solution to check for "hari.cfm" and replace it
>   with "http://hari.cfm"

In your XML, `"hari.cfm"` is not just a string - it's a *namespace URI*. As such, it cannot be replaced by string manipulation.

What you are really asking for is to move nodes from one namespace to another. In your case, this could be accomplished by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old-hari="hari.cfm">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old-hari:*">
    <xsl:element name="hari:{local-name()}" namespace="http://hari.cfm">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This perfectly fixes my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:hari="hari.cfm">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="soap:*">
    <xsl:element name="soap:{local-name()}" namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hari:*">
    <xsl:element name="hari:{local-name()}" namespace="http://hari.cfm">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```